# JavaScript function name alt()

Tags: javascript, html, function

If the function name is "alt", I get the error: "alt is not a function". All other names work. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alt('dato',28);"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
                alt = function(name,age){
                    alert(name + "  " + age);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please change function name from "alt" to anything else allowed, to see that it works.

Can anybody explain what is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that within the `onclick` attribute, `this` refers to the element that has the attribute attached. Now, `alt` is a standard attribute name, and it's going to start out as unset for your button since you didn't specify an `alt` attribute in your HTML (and an `alt` attribute is not needed for an `input`, so there's no need to add one).

In short, `alt` refers not to the global variable `window.alt` that you set in your script, but refers to the element's `alt` attribute, which starts out unset.

So when you run `onclick="alt('dato',28);"`, it's implicitly being interpreted as this: `onclick="this.alt('dato',28);"`.

To get the `alt` that you set in your global scope, instead of the `alt` that's a part of every HTML element, you need to explicitly reach into the global scope, like this:

```
onclick="window.alt('dato',28);"
```

Comment: i was thinking something similar. everything is clear now. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, since you use an [event handler content attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes), your global function `window.alt` is shadowed by `HTMLInputElement.prototype.alt`

This behavior is explained in [step 10](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes:script-execution-environment-2) of [getting the current value of the event handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler):

> **Lexical Environment Scope**
>
> 1. If *H* is an element's [event handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers), then let *Scope* be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(*document*, the *global environment*).
>
>    Otherwise, *H* is a [`Window`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#window) object's [event handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers): let
>      *Scope* be the *global environment*.
> 2. If *form owner* is not null, let *Scope* be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(*form owner*, *Scope*).
> 3. If *element* is not null, let *Scope* be the result of NewObjectEnvironment(*element, Scope*).
>
> Note: *NewObjectEnvironment() is defined in ECMAScript edition 5 section [10.2.2.3 NewObjectEnvironment (O, E)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.2.3)*

That means that the scope of the target element shadows the global scope.

Therefore, you can

- Rename your function

  ```js
  function alt__(name,age){
    alert(name + "  " + age);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alt__('dato',28)" />
  ```
- Use `window.alt` (assuming `window` has not been shadowed):

  ```html
  <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="window.alt('dato',28)" />
  ```

  ```js
  function alt(name,age){
    alert(name + "  " + age);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="window.alt('dato',28)" />
  ```
- Use an [event handler IDL attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes) instead of a [content attribute one](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes):

  ```js
  theInput.onclick = function(){ alt('dato',28); });
  ```

  ```js
  function alt(name,age){
    alert(name + "  " + age);
  }
  document.querySelector('input').onclick = function(){
    alt('dato',28);
  };
  ```

  ```html
  <input type="button" value="click me" />
  ```
- Use an [event listener](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) instead of an [event handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers):

  ```js
  theInput.addEventListener('click', function(){ alt('dato',28); });
  ```

  ```js
  function alt(name,age){
    alert(name + "  " + age);
  }
  document.querySelector('input')


  ----------

  .addEventListener('click', function(){
    alt('dato',28);
  });
  ```

  ```html
  <input type="button" value="click me" />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use html attribute names as functions within the attribute values because it references the attribute value.

for example

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="console.log(value)" />
```

will console log `"click me"`

http://jsfiddle.net/z45dbxL4/

The `this` is implied. So it's the same as

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="console.log(this.value)" />
```